# Selecting another <h:selectOneRadio> from inside one <h:selectOneRadio>

Tags: javascript, jsf, facelets, selectoneradio

I am trying to make an Facelet on which there are two rows each containing two radio buttons are there. I want to make such that if first radio button is selected in first rows, the second radio button in second row should get selected and vice versa. I am trying to use JavaScript but still the changes are not reflected in the browser.

Here is the Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function radioSelect(val){
    if(val.id == "encrypted:1")
{
document.getElementById("protected:0").value = "false";
document.getElementById("protected:1").value = "true";
}
else
{
document.getElementById("protected:0").value = "true";
document.getElementById("protected:1").value = "false";
}

}
</script>
```

And here is the piece of code from my Facelet file:

```
<h:selectOneRadio id="encrypted"
                value="#{uploadFileBean.encryption}" onclick="radioSelect(this);">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="true"></f:selectItem>
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="false"></f:selectItem>
            </h:selectOneRadio>
<h:selectOneRadio id="protected"
                value="#{uploadFileBean.fileprotected}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="true"></f:selectItem>
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="false"></f:selectItem>
            </h:selectOneRadio>
```

---

Well When I am trying to write this JavaScript Function the Ajax Change is not working.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function radioSelect(val){
if(val.id == "encrypted:1")
{
document.getElementById("protected:0").value = "false";
document.getElementById("protected:1").value = "true";
}
if(val.id == "protected:1")
{
document.getElementById("encrypted:0").value = "false";
document.getElementById("encrypted:1").value = "true";
}
if(val.id == "encrypted:0")
{
document.getElementById("protected:0").value = "false";
document.getElementById("protected:1").value = "true";
}
if(val.id == "protected:0")
{
document.getElementById("encrypted:0").value = "true";
document.getElementById("encrypted:1").value = "false";
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure that should'nt be `document.getElementById("protected")`, as I don't see a `:0` in there? And setting the value does'nt check the radio button !

Comment: I think you need to re-render the components depending upon which radio button has the action performed.

Comment: Yeah I have tried "protected" but while debugging on Chrome i can't find a value attribute so i have used a protected:0 so as to change it's value but it is not doing that.

Comment: @dShringi - I am not getting what you mean be Re-rendring the components?

Comment: As you've changed the value of the component, you need to re-render it using `<f:ajax render="otherRadioGroup">` .

Comment: Just two things-
Where Should i write <f:ajax> code and should i give the otherradiogroup's ID in place of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript you've used is working perfectly also when you change the value its getting changed, however to reflect these changes on the facelet you need to update the component which is holding the value of you've changed.

The `f:ajax` tag will do the needful here, as it will update the all the components on the facelet whose id is provided in the `render` attribute. Hence the below code will update the other component each time some action is performed on any of the `h:selectOneRadio`.

```
<h:selectOneRadio id="encrypted" value="#{uploadFileBean.encryption}" onclick="radioSelect(this);">
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="true"></f:selectItem>
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="false"></f:selectItem>
   <f:ajax render="protected">
</h:selectOneRadio>
<h:selectOneRadio id="protected" value="#{uploadFileBean.fileprotected}">
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="true"></f:selectItem>
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="false"></f:selectItem>
   <f:ajax render="encrypted">
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

Comment: Please explain the problem and solution in words as well instead of making it a localized search&find game.

Comment: @BalusC I didn't mentioned that in answer as I've already explained that in comments that it needs to re-render the component after the value is changed. And as the OP asked me to tell where to put the `f:ajax`, I provided the code.

Comment: Comments can be deleted. Answers ought to be self-containing.

Comment: @BalusC Quiet true, will update my answer and keep it in mind.